# How to read xml file with attributes in java?

Tags: java, xml

I am aware of SO question [Failing to get element values using Element.getAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008864/java-read-xml-attributes) but because I am java begginer, I have additional questions. What I am trying to build is simple application, which will read XML file and then compare it against "golden master." My problem is:

- I have lots of different XML files, which differ in attributes
- The XML files are relatively big. (810 lines of filed - hard to check it by human eye)

Example of file:

```
  <DocumentIdentification v="Unique_ID"/>
  <DocumentVersion v="1"/>
  <DocumentType v="P81"/>
  <SenderIdentification v="TEST-001--123456" codingScheme="A01"/>
  <CreationDateTime v="2012-10-15T13:00:00Z"/>
  <InArea v="10STS-TST------W" codingScheme="A01"/>
  <OutArea v="10YWT-AYXOP01--8" codingScheme="A01"/>
  <TimeSeries>
<Period>
 <TimeInterval v="2012-10-14T22:00Z/2012-10-15T22:00Z"/>
   <Resolution v="PT15M"/>
        <Interval>
            <Pos v="1"/>
            <Qty v="500"/>
        </Interval>
        <Interval>
            <Pos v="2"/>
            <Qty v="500"/>
        </Interval>
        <Interval>
            <Pos v="3"/>
                            <Qty v="452"/>
                    </Interval>
                     ...
                     ...
                    <Interval>
            <Pos v="96"/>
                            <Qty v="891"/>
                    </Interval>
               </Period>   
        </TimeSeries>
```

Applying solution from the question mentioned above does not get me much further... I realised that I can cast attributes to `NamedNodeMap` but I dont know how to iterate through it programatically

Yes, I know it sounds much like "do my homework" but what I really need is at least small kick to butt, moving me in correct direction. Thanks for help

Comment: what exactly is the goal of comparing the two files? you might get away by doing things way easier depending on what exactly you need to achieve.

Comment: My idea is: Read the file and compare to expected values: Especially the bits with InArea and OutArea, SendersIdentification - those codes are specific to each file and should be unique to that name

Comment: in that case you are able to go with what Andreas_D somewhat suggests, the namedNodeMap can be obtained from doing node.getAttributes(), then using getNamedItem("v") to get the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `item(int index)` should help iterating through the attributes:

```
NamedNodeMap map = getItFromSomeWhere();
int i = 0;
while ((Node node = map.item(i++)) != null) {
   // node is ith node in the named map
}
```

Comment: How obvious mr Watson ... I feel completly dumb now :)

Comment: just additional question - if I do `node.toString()` will it print the dontent? (dumb dumb dumb)

Comment: I bet you're looking for `Node#getNodeValue` which will be the attributes value (if the node is an attribute). `Node#getNodeName` is the attributes name.