# Parse XML files with strange syntax

Tags: java, xml, sax

First: Is there a name for this type of XML syntax? Second: How can I parse XML file like this with Java, I have looked on som SAX examples, but cant figure out how to parse XML files with this type of syntax. Please give me som advice.

```
<Company>
    <staff Firstname="yong" Lastname="mook" Nickname="mkyoung" Salary="10000" />
    <staff Firstname="low" Lastname="yin fong" Nickname="fong fong" Salary="2000" />
</Company>
```

Comment: That's not a strange syntax. Those are attributes. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Comment: Please see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008864/java-read-xml-attributes> and / or search for how to read XML attributes.

Comment: Actually, parsing XML that makes extensive use of attributes using SAX is much easier than parsing XML that puts the same information in child elements, because an element and all its attributes are delivered in a single call. Perhaps you need a better learning strategy than "looking at examples": why not read a book such as Elliotte Rusty Harold's, which will tell you all you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/) library is great if your XML all fits into memory.

Usage:

```
Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(xmlString);
```

Note: use the 1.6.1 version, as the 2.0 version is not active and development stopped in alpha.